# Использовать объект HttpServletResponse для отправки сообщения с сервера

Tags: java, ajax, spring-security

Возможно ли отправить `ajax` запрос на сервер, там хранить Объект `HttpServletResponse` и отправить response в люое время clent'у?

```
  $.get({
            url: '/startChat',
            async: true,
            success: function (msgToAdd, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert(msgToAdd)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Сервер:

```
private HttpServletResponse firstResponse;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/startChat", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public void startUserChat(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    firstResponse = response;
    }
```

Позже использовать сохраненный объект `firstResponse` для отправки сообщения в `success` функцию `ajax`

Я **попробовал** это сделать, в `success` функцию приходит my-message, но с какой то странной закономерностью в 90% он есть, причем закономерность рандомная.

Проверял объект `httpServletResponse` он одинаков в случае когда msg прикрепляется и когда нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экземпляр объекта `HttpServletResponse` принадлежит контейнеру (веб-серверу), а не вам. Он может быть связан со множеством ресурсов контейнера, о которых прикладной программист в большинстве случаев не знает. Обычно, конкретный `Response` связан с конкретным `Request` и попытка подмены `Response` может привести в неопределённое состояние ваше ПО. Не храните и не пытайтесь подменять такие ресурсы.

Содержимое ответа следует передавать клиенту в HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream(), и хранить кешированный ответ в формате, который можно передать как поток (прямо, или с помощью сериализации). При этом, всегда следует использовать `Response`, только что полученный от контейнера.